# Redirect user back to the original action after login

Tags: c#, asp.net

The sequence of actions that I am trying to accomplish is below.

Context: user can add products to its own account.

1. User tries to add a specific product. (He/she is not login at this point.)
2. In the code behind, I need to redirect the user to login page before I can add the product to user's account.
3. After login, how do I take the system back to the logic to finish up the action in step 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect to the login page, add the original URL in the querystring.
After a successful login, send a to the URL from the querystring.

Comment: I was able to send the user back to the original page by FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(). But I want to add the product to  user's account once redirect back without clicking the add button again. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: @weilin8: Pass that on the querystring too, then check for it after login.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like http://someurl.com/page.aspx?product=1&add=true? Then just check whether "add" is in the querystring.

Comment: Thanks for keep following up with comments

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using FormsAuthentication, if you are not, or don't know what to use, check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx

OK, so when your user tries to access a page that is protected (i.e. they have to be logged it), ASP.NET's forms authentication will send them to the login page, which is best set up in the web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Public/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Public/Default.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

It will also attach a ReturnUrl query string parameter to the that, so the login page knows where they came from:
http://www.example.com/Public/Login.aspx**?ReturnUrl=%2fprivate%2forderproduct.aspx**

Then, in your login page, assuming that they have successfully authenticated, you set the authentication cookie and redirect them back from whence they came:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(someUserIdentifier,isRememberMeSet);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(someUserIdentifier, isRememberMeSet);
```

Of course, if you don't want to use FormsAuthentication, you can still use the concept of the return URL.  Forms authentication just gives you a lot of that for free.

Comment: I can send the user back to the original page by FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(). But how do I take it back to the original action of adding the product to the user's account without having them to click again.